# How to create 'add quantity' input box and embed it inside PHP scripts?

Tags: javascript

> Thanks for those who helped! I have figured it out!

How can I create a input field like the one in the image? And I want to embed it inside $_POST. Thanks for your time :)

[image: add quantity input box]

Comment: Good luck with that :D unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an HTML5 input of type `number`. You use it this way:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourPHPfile.php">
  <input type="number" name="number_input">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When this form is submitted, it will send the selected number to `yourPHPfile.php` and you can retrieve the number from `$_POST['number_input']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use input for the number selecotr and post using a form like so:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="intNumber"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in PHP you can do this

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_POST['intNumber'])){
       $myNumber = $_POST['intNumber']; // intNumber is the name of of your input
    }
?>
```

When the submit button the PHP will be fired.

Hope this helps!